# Row Color based on data property in Angular UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on Angular UI- Grid. I have a scenario in which i need to change the color of the cell of grid using a data value.

[image]

In the above grid the rows that are colored are done based on a data column. I get a column in my grid as BG_COLOR i need to change the color of the row based on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the field you want is cellClass.  There is another question that shows one way to use it here.

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362666/how-to-color-row-on-specific-value-in-angular-ui-grid)

You can also try using cellTemplate to setup your own template for how to render the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row template like this:

```
function rowTemplate() {
    return '<div ng-class="{\'ui-grid-row-bg-red\':row.entity.isError" >' +
                 '<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader}"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
           '</div>';
    }
```

And then define ui-grid-row-bg-red in css:

```
.gridStyle .ui-grid-row-bg-red .ui-grid-cell {
    background-color: #872f2f;
    color: #fff;
 }
```