# How to customize angular ui-grid row background color?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to change background color of angular ui-grid row based on condition so if riskValue is 1 trying to make it red and if value is 2 row background color should be Yellow. Any easy way to achieve this task ?

config.js

```
"columnDefs": [{
        "name": "Ticket Number",
        "field": "ticketNum",
        "width": 120
    },
    {
        "name": "Asset Id ",
        "field": "assetID",
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "Severity",
        "field": "severity",
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "Risk Index",
        "field": "riskIndex",
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "Risk Val",
        "field": "riskValue",
        "cellTemplate": "<div ng-if=\"row.entity.Comments_Col1 != 'none'\" title={{row.entity.riskValue}} \" ><div style='white-space:nowrap;border-bottom: 1px solid red !important; height:100%;width:100%;'>{{row.entity.riskValue}}</div></div>",
        "sort": {
            "direction": "aesc",
            "priority": 0
        },
        "width": 100,
        "visible": false
    }
],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color row on specific value in angular-ui-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362666/how-to-color-row-on-specific-value-in-angular-ui-grid)

Comment: wouldn't add a line such as "background-color": #2dff07 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gridOptions.cellClass`

```
cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    if (row.entity.riskValue === 1) 
        return 'red';
    if (row.entity.riskValue === 2)
        return 'yellow';
}
```

where `red` and `yellow` are css classes.

This method requires adding the function to all of your columnDefs but allows to choose only some columns, which should have changed background color.

Sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xie68a3sT9CXTdCuI3tq?p=preview